# Copying nginx default.config into docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I have problems with copying files into docker image. I'm a newbie in doing this and I have browsed several questions related, but none of them resolved my issue.

```
## base image
FROM node:13.6.0-stretch as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json
RUN npm ci

COPY . /app
RUN npm run build 

FROM nginx:1.17.7
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html #this works

COPY --from=build /app/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf ## this works but.. not 

RUN cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf; return 0 ## cat shows that the file is modified

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

RUN cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf; return 0 ## once again verified
```

So in the log, it looks to be modified to desired file.
But when I check in deployed container:
`sudo docker exec -it 9e2f628dc8a9 cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`
it has the default config provided by nginx.

I tried copying it with different name, still with no results.

Any advises highly appreciated.

Comment: I see you try to copy the default.conf file from /app/nginx/ on your build image . Are you sure the file /app/nginx/default.conf exists in your build image?

Comment: Yes it does, I confirmed that with the `cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`after it was copied (also not in this listing, I confirmed before copying).

Comment: After asking this question, colleague told me that it may be related to the way how container is started - it overrides /conf.d/ folder. 
But then, the question is why it works for `/usr/share/nginx/html`.
I'm not an owner of that whole configured build process and I may be missing some things..